# Overriding global tax settings in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, tax

I've set a global tax on the service fee's, however I need to override those service fees on some products. When I attempt to change the tax settings on the item itself I get the global service fee's and the new one's I changed on the product.

Answer (score 1):

To override tax calcs for single product the easiest way is to just set up a new tax class for all of the tax rates you need in WooCommerce -> Settings -> Tax and then just assign that individual product to the necessary tax rate in the edit product screen